# child_process.on('close') is sometimes painfully slow

Tags: node.js, electron, child-process

I have a electron application that opens a external program (in my case Office), and has to wait for the program to be closed.

the code I wrote works great but sometimes the `child_process.on('close')` event is fired 10 or 20 seconds after the program has closed. The code is:

```
const cp = require("child_process");
child = cp.spawn(path/to/Office.exe + ' "' + path/to/myFile.pptx + '"', {shell: true});
child.on('close', function (code) {
    //do something
});
```

Most of the time it reacts after 1 or 2 seconds which is fine, but sometimes it takes up to 20 seconds until I receive the close event. The program closes fast (according to the task manager), but node seems to wait for something.

I also tried `child.on('exit')`, calling the program with `cp.exec()`and using the `options.stdio: ignore` for spawn, as I thought maybe node is waiting for some stream from the child. But that made no difference.

Does anybody know a safe way to speed that process up?

Comment: Another thing to consider would be that you might have something "memory consuming" or synchronous in your code. That can take a toll on node.

Comment: I recorded at the performance monitor of chromiums debugger in that time. Absolutely nothing in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code and the `close` event triggers with a 0.5-2s delay, bearable i would say.

However, the 20s delay did not occur, but if this problem still persists on your end, you can try the approach below, which consists in checking the `spawn` pid.

```
const pidExists = (pid) => {
    let pidOk = true;
    try {
        process.kill(pid, 0);
    } catch (e) {
        pidOk = false;
    }
    return pidOk;
};
const cp = require("child_process");
// I added the detach option because we won't need that process anymore since we're following the PID.
let child = cp.spawn(path/to/Office.exe + ' "' + path/to/myFile.pptx + '"', {shell: true, detach: true});
let officePID = child.pid; // this is the spawn pid

setInterval(()=>{
    if( pidExists(officePID)){
        console.log('file is still open', new Date().getTime());
    }else{
        console.log('file was closed', new Date().getTime());
        process.exit(0);
    }
}, 500);
```

This is a better approach since you said that the task manager shows you that the program was closed.

Comment: That's an interesting approach. I'll try if I can adapt it. PID is of course from the shell, not Office. so sending the kill signal crashes my application (for whatever reason). But it's very handy for observing where the timing gets stuck.

Comment: Yes, it is the shell pid, i just wanted it to be detached from electron to be sure that the app doesn't interfere with it, and since you have the shell pid, now it's just a monitoring game. Just replace the `process.exit` with a callback/method or something, i used the process.exit upon testing this. `pidExists` won't exit the main app